# Running MRTK2 project gives " Failed to resolve System.Reflection.BindingFlags"

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to port my project over from Unity 2017 LTS to 2018 LTS and MRTK2. Everything was going pretty smoothly until I tried to run the project on an HoloLens 1 emulator.

I get the following error:

```
1>  System.Exception: Failed to resolve System.Reflection.BindingFlags
1>     at Unity.ModuleContext.Retarget(TypeReference type, GenericContext context)
1>     at Unity.ModuleContext.Retarget(MethodReference method, GenericContext context)
1>     at Unity.FixReferencesStep.Visit(MethodDefinition method, GenericContext context)
1>     at Unity.FixReferencesStep.Visit(TypeDefinition type)
1>     at Unity.TypeDefinitionDispatcher.DispatchType(TypeDefinition type)
1>     at Unity.TypeDefinitionDispatcher.DispatchType(TypeDefinition type)
1>     at Unity.TypeDefinitionDispatcher..ctor(ModuleDefinition module, ITypeDefinitionVisitor visitor)
1>     at Unity.FixReferencesStep.ProcessModule()
1>     at Unity.ModuleStep.Execute()
1>     at Unity.FixReferencesStep.Execute()
1>     at Unity.Step.Execute(OperationContext operationContext, IStepContext previousStepContext)
1>     at Unity.Operation.Execute()
1>     at Unity.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Searching for this error gave me nothing, I have not changed the project that Unity builds. I am running it in `Debug` and for `x86`. I am building through the normal Unity Build window.

Using `Minimum Platform Version 10.0.17134.0` and `Target SDK Version 10.0.18362.0`

This also happens with a new empty Unity project, building an example will also give this error.

Comment: dotNET version updated?

Comment: In Unity? I have `Scripting Runtime Version` on `.Net 4.x Equivalent` `Scripting Backend` on `.NET` and `Api Compatibility Level` at `.Net 4.x`

Comment: @AndreyChistyakov I've just tested, and this also happens with a completely new project. Empty Unity project with only MRTK 2, building an example will also give this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizing this may not just have been me, I submitted [an issue in the MRTK github](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/4878). It turns out this is a bug in Visual Studio, and they are working on resolving it with Microsoft.

[There's two ways to solve it](https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-while-building-uwp-app-with-min-platform-version-10-0-16299-0.685918/), either target Windows version 15063 as the min version or change the *yourpoject*.csproj.

If you don't want to change the min version these are the steps to take:

1. Open *yourproject*.csproj in a texteditor
2. Find the line `<Target Name="BeforeResolveReferences" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' == 'true'">`
3. Replace with:

   ```
   <UsingTask TaskName="FixProjectJson" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
       <ParameterGroup />
       <Task>
         <Using Namespace="System" />
         <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
         <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
           <![CDATA[File.WriteAllText("project.lock.json", File.ReadAllText("project.lock.json").Replace("ref/netstandard1.5/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll", "ref/netstandard1.3/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll"));]]>
         </Code>
       </Task>
     </UsingTask>
     <Target Name="BeforeResolveReferences" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' == 'true'">
   ```
4. Find the line `<Message Importance="high" Text="Running AssemblyConverter..." />`
5. Replace with:

   ```
   <Message Importance="high" Text="Running AssemblyConverter..." />
   <FixProjectJson />
   ```

After doing this, my project finally compiled and I was able to run it in the HoloLens 2 Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and to fix it I changed to il2cpp backend.

Comment: That would work, except I need to be on the .net backend for a little while longer.